# Ember 2.0 without Ember cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Seems nowadays everything including loading modules is generated from embercli.

Is it possible to create a emberjs 2.0 application without the use of ember-cli?

What are some limitations of not using ember-cli?

Comment: I think it is possible (I used 1.10 without ember-cli) but I would not suggest trying, because it is a fight vs framework and will make your life harder. Anyway, you will need some tool to build your application (make single minified js file).

Comment: If your concern is with deploying/serving a separate front-end with CLI, keep in mind you could take advantage of CLI for organizing and building your assets without actually using it to serve. But as Gennady said, I wouldn't recommend this and you're bound to have some pains. You'll also find that more addons will stop including documentation and builds for non-CLI use (a lot already have).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it definitely still is.  I support 5 ember applications at my work.  2 of which live on the ASP.Net stack, 3 are on a Java stack.  The 2 on the ASP.Net stack aren't using ember-cli and work perfectly fine as a global application.

Here, I've created an ember app without ember-cli:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xeqevogado/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Kingpin2k that link might not have worked, it's currently linking to the default Ember JSBin setup with no additional code. Or is that what you intended?

Comment: I see the JS Bin is Ember 1.11.1. Is this still possible  with ember 2.0 ?

Comment: Hah, sorry, it was just a plain example of a 2.0 app.  And it's 2.0, the 1.11.1 is jquery not the ember version ;) check the console

Comment: @Kingpin2k +1 for the fun canvas app

Comment: Very cool... can you show an example using Models and DS.JSONAPIAdapter ?  For some reason in 2.x, anytime I use DS.Model etc it doesn't work like it did in 1.12.x